# Why doesn't div:hover work with jquery .animate?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I want to create a search form animated with jquery. **[I have already done](http://www.fuiba.com/ux/search/ndx.html)** but I have a div called .search-icon with a background on :hover that doesn't work:

```
.search-icon:hover {
            background: url(search-icon-hover.png) no-repeat 50% 50% !important;
        }
```

The problem may be caused by jquery animation:

```
$('.wrapper-simple .search-icon').animate({'left': '195px'})
```

but I don't understand where!
Please help!

Thank you!

Comment: There must be some issue with your link because css hover will work fine with jQuery animate.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? When I hover over the icon, it turns orange. What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `pointer-events:none` from the

```
.wrapper-simple .search-icon{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

which specifically makes the pointer events, like mouse over, to be ignored by the CSS, only on some Firefox / Webkit browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Your hover works just fine, but you have your submit button covering it up.